# Ajax With jQuery Effect

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to incorporate jQUery effects with AJAX in the following way:

```
<script>
    $('#navbar a').click(function(){
        var url=$(this).attr('href');
        $('#innerwrap').hide("slide",{direction:"down"},1000).load(url + ' #innerwrap').show("slide",{direction:"up"},1000);
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Essentially, each of my html files have an `innerwrap` div that holds all of the content.

I want the current `#innerwrap` to slide down then the next `#innerwrap` in the clicked navbar location to slide up. Now I know the code's not completely broken because the content DOES gets loaded, but the effect just doesn't seem to happen.

I have other cool jQuery effects on my homepage like a slider and some hover effects for specific divisions. Could they all be conflicting with the AJAX jQuery effect?

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to make any suggestions. Can you place it in a fiddle? From what you describing, I am guessing you are using more than one div with an ID of #innerwrap. You should never have more than one element with the same ID. That's why classes were made.

Comment: How do I create multiple HTML files in a fiddle? The innerwrap div is in two separate html files. I changed it to a class though so thank you for that help, I will do that from now on.